# Как убрать разрывы

Tags: javascript

Решил создать динамический объект на странице, аналогичный collapse, только раскрывается в обе стороны. Однако есть одна проблема, которую не знаю как решить: при схлопывании элемента обратно (при повторном нажатии) появляются разрывы (надо внимательно присмотреться, при увеличении изменяемой ширины разрывы становятся больше), так как передвижение боковых блоков идет не в такт с изменением ширины центрального блока (хотя параметры transition указаны одинаковые). Как от них можно избавиться?

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v2ww4czm/11/)

[image: разрывы]

```js
function moveBlocks(id) {
  var leftBlock = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName('block1')[0];
  var rightBlock = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName('block2')[0];
  var textBlock = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[2];
  var cStyle = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(id).childNodes[2]);
  leftBlock.style.transition = "ease 0.75s";
  rightBlock.style.transition = "ease 0.75s";
  textBlock.style.transition = "ease 0.75s, padding 0.0s";
  if (cStyle.width == "0px") {
    leftBlock.style.transform = "translateX(-100px)";
    rightBlock.style.transform = "translateX(100px)";
    textBlock.style.width = "200px";
    textBlock.style.marginLeft = "-100px";
    textBlock.style.padding = "5px 0 0 5px";
    leftBlock.textContent = "";
    rightBlock.textContent = "";
  }
  if (cStyle.width == "200px") {
    leftBlock.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
    rightBlock.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
    textBlock.style.width = "0px";
    textBlock.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    setTimeout(function() {
      leftBlock.textContent = "Узнать";
      rightBlock.textContent = "больше";
    }, 850);
  }

}
```

```css
.bigblock {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.bigblock:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.textblock {
  height: 141px;
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 2px #AFEEEE solid;
  border-bottom: 2px #AFEEEE solid;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #AFEEEE;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.block1 {
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 40px;
}

.block2 {
  border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="bb1" class="bigblock" onclick="moveBlocks(this.id);">
  <div class="block block1">Узнать
  </div>
  <div class="textblock">Здесь расположена различного рода информация.
  </div>
  <div class="block block2">больше
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы сильно усложнили, по-моему. Я, по крайней мере, не увидел никакой необходимости в такой куче блоков (из-за которых и появляется проблема) и js-кода. Все гораздо проще.

Один блок-родитель, с фоном. Внутри него один блок с текстом "узнать больше", который исчезает при клике, другой блок, невидимый по-умолчанию, белый с расширенной информацией. Все анимации решаются чистым css.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/rncfLpgh/)

```css
    .bigblock {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #AFEEEE; 
  text-align: center;
  transition: width 0.75s 0s ease;
}
.text-more{
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.75s ease;
}
.textblock {
  height: 138px;
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 2px;  
  transition: all 0.75s 0s ease;
  background: white;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.bigblock.open{
  width: 400px;
}
.bigblock.open .text-more{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.bigblock.open .textblock{
  width: 200px;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bb1" class="bigblock" onclick="this.classList.toggle('open');">
    <div class="text-more">Узнать больше</div>
  <div class="textblock">Здесь расположена различного рода информация.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: фишка элемента была в том, что блок изначально был маленький, а при необходимости расширяется и выдает подробную информацию, у вас, как я понял, блок все время имеет фиксированный размер, а это не то, что задумывалось

Comment: @aabb не понял вас. вы работу моего примера смотрели? целых два добавлено, на jsfiddle и здесь. он работает, насколько я могу судить, так же, как ваш. блок расширяется.

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь, может быть я чего-то действительно прямо в упор не понимаю, но вот 2 скриншота, на 1-ом пример работы моего кода, на 2-ом - вашего, и я вижу 1 различие
[1]: http://pixs.ru/showimage/1png_8458551_29780403.png
[2]: http://pixs.ru/showimage/2png_8477656_29780407.png

Comment: @aabb спасибо, теперь я вас понял. упустил эту мелочь. но это решается буквально двумя строчками css. Я вам дал верное направление, а доработать код до идеального вы можете, полагаю, сами. Свой пример исправил к нужному вам виду и здесь и на jsfiddle.

Comment: Большое спасибо, это то, что нужно!